# What were the common crew ranks on WWII US Navy flying boats and bombers?

Tags: military, crew, seaplane, wwii, us-navy

I have been trying to figure this out for some time, but have not had much luck elsewhere. I have found info on USAAF bombers, and what ranks the crewmembers often had, but nothing for larger navy aircraft.

I know Pan-Am's Boeing 314 Clipper flying boat was operated by the US Navy for some time during WWII, but I don't know if the USN operated any heavy bombers or other large aircraft. If they did, what would the ranks of the crew (pilot/plane commander, co-pilot, flight engineer, bombardier, radioman, navigator, gunners, etc.) be?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! If you don't get a good answer here you might also try [history.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/), they have a lot of questions about military history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The Navy did operate some large aircraft, notably the [PB4Y-1 Liberator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolidated_B-24_Liberator#PB4Y-1) and PB4Y-2 Privateer, variants of the B-24 Liberator. This was a late-war addition, the first being delivered in 1944 with the majority being delivered after the war. It was difficult to find crew compositions - the best bet I had was searching for reports of crashes based off of [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidents_and_incidents_involving_the_Consolidated_B-24_Liberator), but the newspaper clippings I found did not mention any crews.

There was a post-WWII (1950) [shoot-down of a Navy PB4Y-2](https://stationhypo.com/2018/04/08/remembering-the-crew-members-of-u-s-navy-pb4y-2-shootdown-by-the-soviets-april-8-1950/) by the Soviets and the article does have the list of the crew members that went down, but without the crew positions (notes added based off of information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_Navy_ratings). This was an electronic intelligence flight, but the crew ranks would have been similar for the flight crew at least. Note: Navy enlisted have ranks and rates, rates being associated with their profession and as such will often be more difficult to determine where there is little information.

- LT Howard W. Seeschaf
- LT John H. Fette
- LTJG Robert D. Reynolds
- ENS Tommy L. Burgess (Ensign/O-1)
- AT1 Frank L. Beckman (Avionics Electronic Technician)
- AL3 Joseph J. Bourassa (Aviation Electronics Man)
- AD 1 Joseph H. Danens (Aviation Machinist's Mate)
- CT3 Edward J. Purcell (Communications Technician)
- AN Joseph N. Rinnier (Airman)
- AD 1 Jack W. Thomas (Aviation Machinist's Mate)